# How to connect LND to bitcoind RPC with authentication cookie stored in a custom folder?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, lightning-network-daemon, authentication

I configured bitcoind RPC to authenticate clients with an authentication cookie. However I cant figure out if it's possible to use this method with lnd while connecting to bitcoind RPC.

I would like to clarify that I'm running bitcoind and lnd in two separated docker containers that share a volume where bitcoind save the authentication cookie. The problem is that lnd doesn't allow to specify the folder in which it could find the cookie... In bitcoin.conf for exemple you can specify the path where you can find the authentication cookie of the tor control port for example...

Someone knows how to do this in lnd ? Is it possible ?

Thank you!

Comment: It should be possible: https://lightningwiki.net/index.php/RPC_auth_for_bitcoind

Comment: RPCauth is not the authentication cookie, with authentication cookie you don't need to create a password, a cookie is generated and shared between bitcoind and lnd on the same file system or shared folder...

Answer (score 2):

It is supported according to the [LND installation guide](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md)

> NOTE:
>
> The auth parameters rpcuser and rpcpass parameters can typically be determined by lnd for a bitcoind instance running under the same user, including when using cookie auth. In this case, you can exclude them from the lnd options entirely.

Comment: I'm running bitcoind and lnd in two separated docker containers that share a volume where bitcoind save the authentication cookie. The problem is that lnd doesn't allow to specify the folder in which it could find the cookie... In bitcoin.conf for exemple you can specify the path where you can find the authentication cookie of the tor control port...

Answer (score 0):

The auth cookie lives in the `data_dir` for `bitcoind`.

lnd finds the `data_dir` by first finding the `bitcoin.conf` file, which it finds based on the `bitcoind.dir` argument passed at runtime. It then parses that for the `data_dir` directive.

You can see this in the src code:
https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/config.go#L1505

So, if you are using a non-default location for your `data_dir` you need to ensure that you have a `data_dir` directive in your `bitcoin.conf` file and that you pass the `bitcoind.dir` at runtime.

Note: lnd won't find your `data_dir` directive if you preface it with `main` ot `test`.